# I want to push User Login history data from one database server to other server table. Please suggest how to proceed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Insert rows of one table to another db server

Answer (score 1):

You may use linked server or openrowset.
Sample openwrowset query:

```
insert into table2
select table1.* from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=MYINSTANCE;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'select * from table1') as table1
```